# Why does Coldfusion occasionally throw an error?

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

For example, I have a page. I can load this page 100 times without error. However sometimes someone gets an error because I get the email that is sent from ColdFusion in the onError method. I don't get them a lot, but I get them more than I would think I should. It's impossible to "debug" because it doesn't happen all the time. Once a day maybe on a given page.

Has anyone seen anything similar.

One exmaple:

```
if((StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.itm, 'video_code') && len(trim(ARGUMENTS.itm.video_code)) || !StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.itm, 'video_code')) == 0) return '<a #class# #target# #linkid# #pageid# href="#url#">#title##fileext#</a>';
    else return '<a class="youtube_video" #target# #linkid# href="http://www.youtube.com/v/#itm.video_code#?version=3&autoplay=1&rel=0&modestbranding=1">#title#</a>';
```

In this page request, the item struct had video_code in there. But when the second line was processed video_code was undefined. I can run the page 100 more times, and this doesn't happen.

```
objectType  class coldfusion.runtime.Struct
element VIDEO_CODE
Resolvedname    ITM
Detail  
ErrNumber   0
Message Element VIDEO_CODE is undefined in ITM.
Type    Expression
Trace:  Template    Line
D:\www\websites\assets\cfcs\menu.cfc    240
D:\www\websites\assets\cfcs\menu.cfc    209
D:\www\websites\assets\cfcs\menu.cfc    15
D:\www\websites\assets\templates\distance_general\campus_index_page.cfm 120
D:\www\websites\domain.com\index.cfm    1
```

Comment: You need to post code for someone to be able to help you, not just say "it errors". If you go in with the attitude that it's **impossible** to debug, then it will be

Comment: There is nothing to post. I am not asking a specific question about a specific line of code. The code in question where the error happens is simply on this specific page load. The other 1000 page loads it's fine. It's a conditional statement based on a SQL query. However I get similar things on other pages in other lines of code. Ramdon errors, that don't happen when I visit the page. Nothing based on SESSION or anything like that.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Fine, I'll post the code, but this is just one instance. There are other seemingly random ones.

Comment: try wrapping it in a try/catch and do a writedebug() and see if it reports anything interesting

Comment: I suggest editing your onError function so that it provides more information.

Comment: Our on error function dumps plenty. I can tell exactly where it's happening, and it's because the statement in question returns true when it should return false. But only every now and then.

Comment: I've downvoted this because whilst I don't dispute there's a problem with the code, the premise of the question is... err... "wayward". That said, I see no reason to CLOSE the question: it's a good demonstration of how cluttered code can be difficult to troubleshoot, and the answers provided are helpful as far as both troubleshooting and problem resolution go.

Comment: These things are *always* possible to debug. Try/catch the erroring line of code and write all the variables contributing the logic out to a log file, to verify they all have the values you expect. This would have solved this issue because you'd've spotted that a combination of events you (and your logic) wasn't expecting. This would have lead you to fix the logic, and the problem would go away.

Comment: I'm used to closing topics once the answer is provided from a different forum.

Comment: There's a difference between marking as resolved and marking a question as "closed" (which can be a misleading term for what the action is intended as).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in your code.

That's the standard automatic response when anyone asks a question like the one you have, because it's *almost always* the case.

There is of course a chance that you've identified a flaw in ColdFusion, but the odds of finding a bug in an established product are  *significantly* lower than those of it being an error in your specific code/config.

Given the convoluted code provided as an example, the probably is very high that it's a bug in your code.

> can programming languages mis-parse at times or anything like that.

Simply, no. There are no parse-level constructs that would make the parser behave differently, and the parsing is done once, then the same compiled code is used (until cleared or server restarted).

> why this would not fail 100 times over and fail once?

Looking again at the example, it may well be a scoping issue - you are checking StructKeyExists on `ARGUMENTS.itm` but are then using simply `itm` in the code. **ColdFusion has threading issues with unscoped variables that can manifest when under heavy load.**

Use [varscoper](http://varscoper.riaforge.org) to check for unscoped variables.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with operator precedence. `!expression == 0` is parsed as `!(expression == 0)`, not `(!expression) == 0`.

Comment: I am not doubting there is bugs in the code I work with. It's been written over the past three years with various programmers. I am asking a general question... can programming languages mis-parse at times or anything like that. I dobut it, but worth asking. It's strage a page cna be processed 100 times over, but once in a while throw an error when nothing changes. Why would it only happen... every once in a while?

Comment: Barmar, not sure - there's an extra closing bracket in there. There's definitely something going on with double negatives and stuff which I can't be bothered deciphering.

Comment: Yeah, misread the brackets. However, the relative precedence of `&&` and `||` could be relevant.

Comment: One of our programmers loved double negatives and ternary operators which makes the code wonderful to sift through.

Comment: _" can programming languages mis-parse at times or anything like that."_ - Simply, no. Parsing is done once, then the same compiled code is used. Given that you haven't scoped itm in the second part, it may be a var scoping issue. **Grab [varscoper](http://varscoper.riaforge.org)** and see what it says.

Comment: I'll take your answer, can you perhaps shed light on why this would not fail 100 times over and fail once?

Comment: So what you are saying, and I guess I have to accept, is that programming languages can't mis-parse, but because I am referencing an unscoped variable, sometimes it may check it correctly and other times not? That doesn't make any sense. It seems it should fail every time or run everytime.

Comment: It's not just scope cascading, there are threading issues with unscoped variables that can happen when under heavy load, but not in regular use.

Comment: Ahhh... Now that makes some sense. We have more of these after a server/application restart and certain times of the year when we are under heavy load.

Comment: If my brain was working right, I would have said that at the start. :)

Comment: That answers my original question. I wasn't trying to be an ass or lazy and not show code. I know there are potential bugs, but knowing how a lot of our code looks, and how bad unscoped variables can be, that puts more importance on unscoped variables. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. I think the title of the question was perhaps the main thing that caused the negative attention / downvotes - wording it as "why am I getting occasional failures?" or similar would probably have helped there.  (Also, examples are good even when it appears there are multiple seemingly-unrelated issues.)

Comment: Noted. On a related note, varscoper doesn't see that as an unscoped variable. So that's fun. Maybe because it's in quotes? I'll play around. Thanks for help. Is there a way I can close the question?

Comment: I think @PeterBoughton's answer above is excellent info, but it's not the right answer over all.

Comment: If arguments.itm exists, then only local.itm (or an itm inside a query loop) will take precedence - a variables.itm wont (which is what varscoper is checking for, and hence why it isn't highlighting this), so yeah, don't think this is the right answer for this example.

Answer (score 2):

It's an actual bug in your code.  The `if` condition is:

```
(StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.itm, 'video_code') && len(trim(ARGUMENTS.itm.video_code)) || !StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.itm, 'video_code')) == 0
```

which means that the `else` condition is:

```
(StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.itm, 'video_code') && len(trim(ARGUMENTS.itm.video_code)) || !StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.itm, 'video_code'))
```

So the `else` clause will be executed when `ARGUMENTS.itm.video_code` exists and is not empty, **or** when it doesn't exist. In the latter case, the reference to `itm.video_code` on the second line will fail.

I can't explain why the error happens intermittently. I think you need to look at the different callers, to see why the argument sometimes doesn't exist.

Comment: I can verify what @Barmar says. As to why it happens intermittently? I presume that the occasions that `arguments.itm` exists but `arguments.itm.video_code` doesn't exist occur only intermittently. The conditional logic you have there is awful to decipher btw. You should revise that if poss. A case in point if the logic was clearler, the logic error would have been easier to spot.

Comment: I had to apply de Morgan's theorem about 4 times to simplify it.

Comment: My head hurts after reading that. I dunno why the logic ain't just if(it exists and it has length) {do it} else {don't do it}. Isn't that what it amounts to (or at least SHOULD amount to)?